# Java keeps returning the value of a variable even after mathimatical process?

Tags: java

**even after the tprice = 75 + (2/10) * distance takes place it still inputs the minvalue as  26.
this program is NOT ALLOWED to contain if statements hence the  Math.Min(tprice, cprice);
Hope this is enough info.**

```
class UserCalc {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int cPrice, tPrice, distance, selfCont, minValue;
        double refund;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the distance by car");
        distance = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the self contribution");
            selfCont = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();

        tPrice = 75 + (2/10) * distance;
        cPrice = 26 + (7/10) * distance;

        minValue = Math.min(tPrice, cPrice);
        System.out.println(minValue);

        refund = minValue * (100 - selfCont)/100;
    }
}
```

Comment: `2/10` is as good as `0`. Use `2.0/10` instead.

Comment: Hello, i changed the type instead of double to a float, i am still getting the error:(

Comment: @user2932121 cPrice and tPrice need to be float, too. I just mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: What he meant is both `(2/10)` and `(7/10)` will always give the result 0 because integer division is used. If you change one of the operands to double like `(2.0/10)`, floating point operations are used and you get the expected result.

Comment: @RohitJain better yet, `0.2` seems easier to read.

Comment: @Cruncher If he wants to keep the formula explicit then I guess (2.0/10.0) will be better , right ?

Comment: @LittleChild I'm pretty sure those aren't 2 different "variables" being coded in with constants (in which case I would prefer to keep the form). I think the `2/10` is just there to say `20%` something which I would prefer to represent as a decimal.

Comment: BTW. I think that it's worth mentioning that Math.min uses the `?:` operator, which essentially an if statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
tPrice = 75 + (2/10) * distance;
cPrice = 26 + (7/10) * distance;
```

`2 / 10` is interpreted as integers, which cannot represent a value behind the comma. This means `2 / 10 = 0.2 = 0`.

resulting in `tPrice = 75` and `cPrice = 26`.

Use `2.0 / 10` to indicate you're using a `double` instead, or `2.0f / 10` to use a float.

You're storing the result in a `float`, but that is only after the operation has finished on integers.

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering a case of integer division. Let's break it up, piece by piece:

```
cPrice = 26 + (7/10) * distance;
```

The order of operations will perform the parentheses first - since you're dividing an integer by an integer, the result (0.7) will be truncated to 0:

```
cPrice = 26 + (0) * distance;
```

Then the multiplication is straightforward, as anything multiplied by 0 is 0:

```
cPrice = 26 + 0;
```

Thus:

```
cPrice = 26;
```

To improve your code, ensure that when you want to maintain precision for division/multiplication, you need to use double values in your calculation:

```
cPrice = 26 + (0.7) * distance;
```

See this article describing the behavior:

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-int-div.html

Answer (score 0):

```
tPrice = 75 + (2/10) * distance;  // loss of
cPrice = 26 + (7/10) * distance;  // precision due to int
```

The above two lines are the problem. You are having a loss of precision due to the usage of `int`. You need to switch to `double`

Instead, try this:

```
tPrice = 75 + (2.0/10.0) * distance;  // loss of
cPrice = 26 + (7.0/10.0) * distance;  // precision due to int
```

Your variables `tPrice` and `cPrice` also need to be double so as to be able to accomodate the numbers after decimal.

Comment: use double refund, cPrice, tPrice, minValue; along with tPrice = 75 + (2.0/10) * distance;
  cPrice = 26 + (7.0/10) * distance;

Comment: Yes, if the range is too large =)

Comment: Those are `double`, not `float`.

Answer (score 0):

int value of `7/10` and `2/10` is `0`. That's the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has mentioned it so far, if you want to continue using an `int` you can rearrange the expression to: `(2*distance)/10`

This is mathematically equivalent, but the integer division will make less of a difference(as it doesn't happen until the end. It's like "rounding" in the middle of a calculation vs. at the end). This will still not give you an exact answer, but it was worth pointing out that order actually matters here. Some cases you really do want an integer answer so it's good to know about how changing the order of operations makes a difference.